# upgrading fos user makes impossible the login step

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I've migrated fos user too. Now I'm able to land on the login page, the problem is when I enter my login and my password I get the error message as if I entered wrong information, I'm sure of my credentials so I thought that maybe new fos user version is using different enrypting passwords algorithm.

The solution is either to set the enryption algorithm myself or to compute again passwords but before that I've to figure out the used algorithm.

Qs: where do I find out which algorithm fos user is using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOSUser Documentation:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Did you configured the encoder ?

What is the value of your password inside the database ?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, actually we decided to put on standby the project migration because it's painful, but now it's clear that the migration it's not an option :/. Anyway, I added the encoders and it still doesn't work which means that my account or just my password (I don't know) isn't recognized. Inside the db I have a encrypted password+algorithm column set to sha512